# Disable all checkboxes, all dropdown lists & textboxes at one shot with Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

I want to disable all checkboxes, all dropdown lists & textboxes (except the buttons) at one shot, those are present in my page.

The below code is not working, Please rectify.

```
$('checkbox').filter('type=[button]').attr("disabled", "disabled");
$('input').filter('type=[button]').attr("disabled", "disabled");
$('select').filter('type=[button]').attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

NB: I dont want to disable the buttons present in my page.

Comment: Attribute selectors go inside square brackets, `[type="button"]` not `type=[button]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you're using jQuery v1.6.*, you should be using `.prop("disabled", true)`.

```
$('input[type="text"], input[type="checkbox"], select').prop("disabled", true);
```

Comment: Thx, But how to exclude certain checkboxes ? Can I do it using filters?

Comment: What do you want to match against? Class? ID? Attribute?

Comment: `input[type="checkbox"][id!="foo"]` and replace `foo` with an ID. Also have a look at http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ for more possibilities.

Comment: Thx Chris. But I ve asked how to exclude certain checkboxes from getting disabled. Anyways, I ll check in the link u ve provided. thx

Comment: Let me try and break it down for you... `input` means jQuery will select all `<input />` elements. Add on `[type="checkbox"]` and jQuery will select only `<input type="checkbox" />` elements. Further, adding on `[id!="foo"]` means jQuery will select all `<input type="checkbox" />` elements *as long as* their `id` is not `id="foo"`.

Comment: @Chris let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2594/discussion-between-biki-and-chris)

Comment: Hi Chris, Can I use the prop for style changes, like ).prop("visibility", "visible") or ("display", "none");

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[type="text"], input[type="checkbox"], select').prop("disabled", true);
```

Comment: NB: I dont want to disable the buttons present in my page.

Comment: Yes, the above doesn't select buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Proper way to set properties is to use .prop if you are using latest jquery.

```
$(":checkbox, select, :text").prop("disabled",true);
```